# How to apply a while in this case?

Tags: bash, while-loop

What I am looking for is that if a number is pressed which does not have any function assigned then the case is executed again and it tells me the options again and that this is done with a while or a for. The problem is that I do not know how to apply it, if someone can explain it to me I would be grateful

```
while false; do

case $OPTION in

        1) echo "You have chosen to stop the container $CONT"
                stop_machine
        ;;

        2) echo "You have chosen to start the container $CONT"
                start_machine
        ;;

        3) echo "You have chosen to manage the RAM of the $CONT container"
                management_ram
        ;;

        4) echo "You have chosen to manage the CPU of the container $CONT"
                cpu_management
        ;;
        *) echo "Option not valid. I stop the script"
                exit ;;



esac

done
```

Comment: The `exit` you now have seems to explicitly counter what you want to do, doesn't it?

Comment: Replace `false` with `true`?

Comment: I want that: if i enter an invalid number i want the program to ask it again

Comment: @KuronekoKB : I think for this kind of loop, `select` would be a better choice than `while`. See the section _Compound Commands_  in the bash man page, which describes the _select_-loop.